# Change method's return type dynamically

Tags: java

I would like to change method's return type dynamically. For example, I have code such this:

```
class A {

}

class B extends A {
    public void animate1() { }
    public void animate2() { }
}

class C extends A {
    public void animate3() { }
    public void animate4() { }
}

class Registry {

    private Map<String, A> mMap;

    public <T> T get(String key) {
        A data = mMap.get(key);

        /*
        * I would like to implement like this:
        * if(data.getClass() == B.class)
        *       T = B;
        * else if(data.getClass() == C.class)
        *       T = C;
        */

        return (T) data;
    }

    public void put(String key, A data) {
        mMap.put(key, data);
    }

}
```

Now I can do this:

```
        mRegistry.put("key_b", new B());
        mRegistry.put("key_c", new C());
        ((B) mRegistry.get("key_b")).animate1();
        ((C) mRegistry.get("key_c")).animate4();
```

I want to implement code like this (without cast):

```
        mRegistry.put("key_b", new B());
        mRegistry.put("key_c", new C());
        mRegistry.get("key_b").animate1();
        mRegistry.get("key_c").animate4();
```

The method can change its return type of following in some data, similar to first code (where it is commented).
Maybe someone knows, how to solve this problem in another way, but without casts outside class Registry?

Comment: interface `A` must have `animate1()` and `animate4()`

Comment: You can't do that without a cast (or without reflection). What would you expect to happen when you call `animate1` on a `C` instance?

Comment: @PeterLawrey - `A` is not an interface

Comment: You have to add animate1 and animate4 to A and implement them in B and C or better use an interface for A.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Each class (such a B or C) have unique set of methods. And yes, I made a mistake (corrected to  mRegistry.get("key_c").animate4(); )

Comment: How about a method `A.animate(int hint)`?

Comment: @IvanSadovyi - It isn't possible to have a unique set of methods with inheritence and what you're trying to do

Comment: @IvanSadovyi the compiler has to determine that the method can be called at compile time. This means you can only call a method which the compiler knows you can call.

Comment: @PeterLawrey So, it was an implicit question :) Can I to tell to compiller, that method exist (or not exist)?

Comment: @IvanSadovyi that is what the cast is for.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I know, but when I using cast outside Registry class, I got a huge code constructions. I can cast value in Registry class, but when I return value with type B, but method's return type is A, value will converted to A and compiler will not recognize it as B without cast, even i casted this in Registry class.

Answer (score 2):

class A must have animate1() and animate4()

```
class A {
    void animate1() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    void animate4() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

so this compiles because the get() method returns an `A`

```
mRegistry.get("key_b").animate1();
mRegistry.get("key_b").animate4();
```

Comment: could make `A` an abstract class

Comment: yes but this would imply to implement both methods animate1 and animate4 in B and C

Comment: @MasterMind You only need to override the methods where needed.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Each class (such a B or C) have unique set of methods.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yep but if it was the case the solution of the answer would be obvious

Comment: @IvanSadovyi the compiler will only let you call a method it knows the object implements.  You could use reflection but that would be more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the keys have a 1-to-1 relationship with classes, that is, you know that you are storing an instance of type X but you are interested on saving a particular instance, you can use the `Class` token as the key:

```
class Registry {

    private Map<Class<? extends A>, A> mMap;

    public <T extends A> T get(Class<T> key) {
        A data = mMap.get(key);
        return (T) data;
    }

    public void put(Class<? extends A> key, A data) {
        mMap.put(key, data);
    }

}

// Usages would look like:
reg.put(C.class, new C());
C myC = reg.get(C.class); // No cast required
```

The reason for the `put` method also requiring the class token instead of it being extracted from the value with `data.getClass()` is twofold:

1. It allows you to register as "the instance for class C" an object that doesn't need to be exactly of class C, but only of a derived type. Thus, if you have `class C1 extends C`, you could do `reg.put(C.class, new C1());` and the object would be retrieved under the key `C.class`.
2. It does not *directly* forbide entering `null`s into the registry (if you want to allow that). Obviously the particular `Map` implementation might not allow it, and it is always the default value returned if you try to get with a non-existing key. However, it might (or might not) be important in your design.